# Using struct arrays in parfor

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I am having trouble using struct arrays in Matlab's parfor loop. The following code has 2 problems I do not understand:

```
s=struct('a',{},'b',{});
if matlabpool('size')==0
  matlabpool open local 2
end

for j = 1:2      
  parfor k=1:4
    fprintf('[%d,%d]\n',k,j)
    s(j,k).a = k;
    s(j,k).b = j;
  end
end
matlabpool close
```

1. It fails with an error `Error using parallel_function (line 589)
   Insufficient number of outputs from right hand side of equal sign to satisfy assignment.`
2. On output, variable `s` is a vector, not an array (as it should be, even if the code breaks before finishing).

**EDIT** the problem is solved if I initialize the struct arrays to the correct size, by:

```
s=struct('a',cell(2,4),'b',cell(2,4));
```

However, I would still be happy to get insights about the problem (e.g is it rally a bug, as suggested by Oleg Komarov)

Comment: For point 2, what do you mean "array" rather than "vector"?  In Matlab there is no distinction.  It looks to me like `s` should be a 2x4 matrix of `struct`s at the end of this code.

Comment: I think it is actually a bug and I recommend to submit a [support equest](http://www.mathworks.it/support/service_requests/contact_support.do?) and keep us updated.

Comment: @jazzbassrob, a vector is a 1xd array (or dx1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was originally working fine for me but then I don't know what happens. In general you need to be careful with parfor loops and there are ample documentation on how to align everything. Two different words of advice. 
First and more importantly, the parfor loop is on the outside loop:

```
function s = foo
s=struct('a',{},'b',{});

parfor j = 1:2      
  for k=1:4
    fprintf('[%d,%d]\n',k,j)
    s(j,k).a = k;
    s(j,k).b = j;
  end
end
```

Two, Matlab gets very picky about writing the main exit variable (i.e. the variable contained in the parfor loop which is indexed to the loop, in your case, `s`). You first want to create a dummy variable that holds all the innerloop information, and then writes to it once at the end of the loops. Example:

```
function s = khal
s=struct('a',{},'b',{});


parfor j = 1:2 
   dummy=struct('a',{},'b',{});
  for k=1:4
    fprintf('[%d,%d]\n',k,j)
    dummy(k).a = k;
    dummy(k).b = j;
  end
  s(j,:) = dummy;
end
```

You don't have a problem here, but it can get complicated in other instances

Comment: Why should the parfor be in the outer loop? If I have outer loop on index [1,2] and inner loop on index [1,...,1000], the inner loop which is longer will not be parallelized, is it?

Comment: there is an overhead cost to having parfor loops, and there are cases where is will be cost effective in having it in the inner-loop (especially if you have more then two pool running), but generally, you should structure the code so that the parfor loop is in the outer-loop. With a pool of 2, it will almost always be faster with parfor in the outer-loop (try and compare...).

Comment: Good answer! Somehow if you index the original struct with the slicing variable of the `parfor loop` (in this case `j`), it works. Indexing in any other way doesn't seem to work. For example, `s(1,:)` doesn't work but `s(j,:)` does!